# Is it a problem to have gaps in the drywall hidden by molding?

Tags: drywall, walls, trim, stairs

We recently had someone repairing the stairs in our home. During the process of removing the old stairs they created these gaps in the drywall (see images), however, they never filled them and simply covered them with molding. Is this an issue we should try and fix or is this normal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Molding is used to cover imperfections all of the time. Some people like to see molding while others do not, that's opinion based. Should you fix it yourselves, that is up to you, do you have to, no. If you anticipate the contractor fixing it, look at your contract. If you believe you were wronged, seek legal counsel.

Comment: Yes. One could argue that covering the raw edges of drywall (and plaster, and window frames...) is the primary purpose of trim moldings. The only time it's a concern is when there isn't substantial backing for the trim and it feels unsupported and mushy.

Answer (score 7):

If you can no longer see the openings in the drywall your contractor did a good job, molding is there to cover the ends at the floor and edges at openings so there is no need to go back it will not change anything as every house I have remodeled and built has some spaces that are covered by molding.

Comment: I fail to see how covering up damage with molding can be considered a "good job". They busted holes in the wall, and covered it up with a few dollars worth of cheap molding, instead of fixing it...

Comment: Even cheap molding is more expensive than sheetrock. From the finished photos it looks like a good job to me.

Comment: Let me rephrase that - they were lazy and unprofessional. I would have fixed the drywall, with the intention off leaving it how I found it, unless the customer specifically requested otherwise. The drywall would not have been cheaper, by any stretch of the imagination - you don't just stick it on the wall and you're done.

Comment: Having sheetrocked many buildings I totally disagree! The final photos look good, this was a professional job by looking at the finish photos. I don't know where you get your trim but even crap composite 1 stick cost more than a sheet and I could have easily cut 1 sheet into 4 pieces to cover up a foot but there would still need to be trim.

Comment: This is becoming a discussion; I gave my opinion instead of down-voting. I'm not debating half-assery tit for tat any further - I wouldn't do this to my customers, period.